# sshfs remount frequently hangs

Tags: linux, mount, sshfs

On Fedora 21 current patches, in a local LAN environment, I'm mounting 2 filesystems with sshfs.  The remote server is on a reliable LAN network, the ssh keys are correctly setup for passwordless login.

So I create an empty directory in my home dir (which is a local filesystem), mount with:

```
sshfs -o default_permissions me@remoteserver:/mntpoint /home/me/mountdir
```

The connection works fine and is very stable, performs well, no complaints.  Then maybe the local machine reboots or something unexpected happens so the connection is broken ungracefully.

Upon reboot, restart, re-attempt, the same command above will hang ... indefinately.  If I control-C it and fusermount -u it, it appears to clean up, but still cannot remount.  But the wierd thing:  if I specify a new mount point in my home dir, it works perfectly again (same remote point).  Works perfectly again until something happens and I have to start all over again.

Reboots of the local machine will not clear it.  The mount directory is verified empty, I've even removed the mount point directory and recreated the same name...  Nope.

Eventually after some trigger, I can go back to an old mount point.  So I end up having about 3-4 dirs like:

```
/home/me/mount.1
/home/me/mount.2
...
/home/me/mount.4
```

before I can go back to mount.1.

Sometimes it works the first time, especially if I properly unmount it, but most of the time it doesn't.

Any ideas of how to clear whatever sshfs is holding.  I can't find anything in any /etc file.

Totally frustrated.

Comment: I'm no expert, but I think this question would be better answered somewhere like superuser or the unix StackExchange site.  I think StackOverflow is specifically about programming questions.

Comment: @Vi3GameHkr Expert or not, you're right.